# How do you load binary files compressed in gzip format?

Tags: python, gzip, binaryfiles, tar

To begin with, let me preface this by saying I am not a Computer Scientist or Software Engineer. I am a physics student, so I apologize if this question is dumb.

I have been messing with machine learning models on PyTorch and learning how to use them, how they work, etc. However, the issue is the datasets. I have used MNIST digits and fashion and the other datasets in PyTorch, but I want to learn how to actually download and use the other datasets out there (ImageNet, Animals with Attributes, SUN, to name a few).

When I download these files (to be specific, the SUN labels with attributes and the corresponding images) they all are in .tar.gz format. As I understand it, .gz stands for gzip, which is a compression algorithm. However, I have several questions:

1. What even is a .tar file and why is it that most datasets come in this format?
2. How do you actually uncompress those gzip files in code (and more importantly, what do each of the lines of code actually do)?
3. I have tried to uncompress the MNIST files from the source using some tutorials on gzip, but they seem to be in "binary." What exactly does it mean for them to be in binary once uncompressed, and how do you go from binary to arrays?

I have seen some tutorials and code on HOW to do some of these things, but in all honesty all that I do is just copy code and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, but regardless I have no idea why, or what the code even does. I have by now a fairly good grasp on how to train and test models on PyTorch, but my issue is more on the computer side and what those files even are, and what the lines of code even do when transforming those files into usable arrays. Explain the steps to me like I have no idea how anything computer works, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

A .tar.gz file is built in two steps. First, a structure of files and directories are encoded into a single stream of bytes with a simple header of 512 bytes providing information on the file or directory, including the length of the file, followed by the file data (if it's not a directory) in an integer number of 512-byte blocks. That is a .tar "tape archive" file. The word "tape" refers to the fact that these were originally stored on reels of magnetic tape when our ancestors lived in caves.

That's all well and good, but you'd also like to compress the data to take up less space on your storage medium. Most text and executables files, and many other file types, tend to be losslessly compressible. So you run the .tar file through a single-file compressor called gzip. gzip will append ".gz" to the file name to indicate the compression. So you end up with a .tar.gz file.

The tar utility will run gzip itself if you ask, so you don't need to invoke gzip separately. Also the two steps are really done as one step at the same time, with the resulting stream of bytes from tar being run through gzip as they are being generated. Or that same process in reverse when extracting the archive.

You did not say what sort of system you are running on. On Linux or macOS, you would use the tar command like this to archive a directory:

```
tar czf result.tar.gz mydirectory
```

and this to extract:

```
tar xzf result.tar.gz
```

which will create `mydirectory` in your current directory.